# Replace object values lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lets say I have an object

```
var users = [
  { Mike:    'true' },
  { Tony:    'True' },
  { Ismael:  'RU' }
];
```

I have this problem where I want to normalise my object, basically replace "true" or "True" with a boolean `true` anything else should be `false`.

By the way I may have the syntax for `users` wrong, chrome is telling me `users.constructor == Object` and not `Array`.

How can I achieve this using lodash?

Comment: Does `'RU'` become `false`?

Comment: yes it becomes false

Comment: sorry edited, it should be false. so anything with "true" or "True" should be true, anything else false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use lodash. You can use native [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const users = [
  { Mike: 'true' },
  { Tony: 'True' },
  { Ismael: 'RU' },
];
const normalisedUsers = users.map(user =>
  // Get keys of the object
  Object.keys(user)
   // Map them to [key, value] pairs
   .map(key => [key, user[key].toLowerCase() === 'true'])
   // Turn the [key, value] pairs back to an object
   .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (obj[key] = value, obj), {})
);
console.log(normalisedUsers);
```

Functional programming FTW!

Comment: Several answers (including this one) start with, essentially, "you don't need lodash for that". And how many more across SO! Although it is useful to point to alternate, possibly simpler solutions, my immediate reaction is always: "And you're not answering the question!"

Answer (score 13):

In Lodash, you can use [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#mapValues):

```js
const users = [
  { Mike: 'true' },
  { Tony: 'True' },
  { Ismael: 'RU' },
];
const normalisedUsers = users.map(user =>
  _.mapValues(user, val => val.toLowerCase() === 'true')
);
console.log(normalisedUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, it's much simpler than my solution.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need lodash to achieve this, just use a for loop. Here is an example

```
var users = [
  { Mike:    'true' },
  { Tony:    'True' },
  { Ismael:  'RU' }
];

for (key in users) {
   if (users[key] == 'true' || users[key] == 'True') {
      users[key] = true
   } else {
     users[key] = false
   }
}
```

What this is doing is, if your value is 'true' or 'True' then assign a boolean val of true to your object & else assign false.

### Edit

You could also do it the shorthand way, as suggested by **4castle**:

```
users[key] = users[key] == 'true' || users[key] == 'True';
```

Simply replace the if/else block with this one line.

Comment: Perhaps more simply: `users[key] = users[key] === 'true' || users[key] === 'True';`